# Where is "All My Files" folder?

Tags: folders, filesystem

I used to think "All My Files" is not a real folder but it turns out otherwise. I accidentally moved some of my files into "All My Files" folder and now they are disappeared! How can I locate "All My Files" folder?

Comment: Okay never mind, I discovered that All My Files folder is Documents folder. When you move files to this folder they end up in Documents folder.

Comment: Just because "When you move files to this folder they end up in Documents folder." does not mean "All My Files folder is Documents folder." They're obviously not the same...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, All My Files is a folder, but not the way you'd expect it to be. It exists at the path `/System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/Contents/Resources/MyLibraries/myDocuments.cannedSearch`. It is a special type of folder, called a *bundle*, that has an extension. You can usually access the inner part of these by right-clicking and choosing "Show Package Contents", but with All My Files you can't due to Finder's special treatment of it.

The bundle contains a file called `search.savedSearch` which is just a Smart Folder property list. This is a search for all files within your home directory.

In your case, this doesn't matter, because when you drag something into the All My Files folder, it goes to `~/Documents`. The odd thing about this is it only happens for All My Files, and not other Smart Folders, which don't allow you to drag-and-drop files into them.

Answer (score 0):

The All My Files is not a real folder unlike others.

Is is simply a collection of all files on your mac.

They come from all kind of different folders.